# SQL if date is null, have empty varchar, if not null convert date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a section of my query:

```
CASE
   WHEN COALESCE(V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.ID187, '') = '' 
      THEN ' ' 
      ELSE CONVERT(date, V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.ID187) 
END AS 'actualFinish'
```

What I am trying to do here is say if this date is null or empty then have ' ' else convert it to a date, but when I have a null value it returns `1900-01-01` how come?

I have even tried CONVERT(varchar, ' ') and that didn't do anything?

Comment: ***A column in a result set can't be of two data types.***  you either have a date data type which ' ' isn't a valid value or you have a varchar data type that isn't date.  I don't see in your example where you explicity try to set the date to NULL not empty set.

Comment: An empty string converts to 0 when cast to int and a 0 casts to the base date of 1900-01-01 so I presume in this case the implicit cast behaviour is transitive and an empty string cast to datetime casts to that too.

Comment: What data type do you expect the output to be?  Date or varchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nulls exist for a reason.  NULL is the emptyset, whereas '' means something that has been mapped to 0 which is `1900-01-01` as a date.

You can convert the date to a varchar to workaround this:

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.ID187, '') = '' THEN ' ' ELSE  CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(date, V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.ID187)) END AS 'actualFinish'
```

Or best practice is to keep the nulls in your actualFinish column so that you can maintain the column type of date.